# How to break two positioned top elements?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have two elements both positioned on top at 0px. But, both are overlaying each other and I want to separate them without changing their position property.

```css
h2 {
  position: fixed;
  left: 100px;
  top: 0px;
}

p {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <h2>This is a heading with a fixed position</h2>
  <p>This is a paragraph with an absolute position</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "separate"?

Comment: Why do they need to maintain their current position property?

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to add a [`top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top) value to the paragraph so it's positioned below the heading.

```css
h2 {
  position: fixed;
  left: 100px;
  top: 0;
}

p {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<h2>This is a heading with a fixed position</h2>
<p>This is a paragraph with an absolute position</p>
```

However, if the heading is long enough to wrap to multiple lines, the position of the paragraph won't adjust accordingly and text will start overlapping again.

Although you mentioned you don't want to change the `position` of the elements, a more flexible approach might be to wrap the elements in a single container and position that container absolutely (or fixed):

```css
#container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h2>This is a heading that might have enough text to wrap to another line</h2>
  <p>This is a paragraph</p>
</div>
```